# Inner Shadow getting aliased when skewed

Tags: css, css-shapes, css-transforms, box-shadow

As shown in the pic, the inset shadow becomes aliased when I use

```
-webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
```

It occurs both on chrome and in firefox, is there an work-around?

**Screen print:**

[image: screenshot of skewed block]

```css
    #BlockOutside {
   background-color: #cfcfcf;
   padding: 5px;
   padding-left: 3px;
   padding-right: 3px;
   height: 25px;
   width: 15px;
   -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
    }
    #BlockInside {
   background-color: gray;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="BlockOutside">
  <div id="BlockInside"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the `transform` that is getting applied on the parent element. There is no way to get rid of this completely but you can remove it to a significant extent by making the back-face hidden and also adding a `translateZ(0)` (like mentioned in [Woodrow Barlow's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590407/inner-shadow-getting-aliased-when-skewed/31590583#comment51133896_31590583)). The extra transform will not cause any undesired effects because it is only translating by 0px.

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: skew(10deg) translateZ(0); /* translateZ(0) was added */
```

**Note:** The `backface-visibility` property does need browser prefixes. I have used prefix-free library in the snippet to avoid writing the prefixed versions.

```css
#BlockOutside {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  transform: skew(10deg) translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#BlockInside {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div id="BlockOutside">
  <div id="BlockInside"></div>
</div>
```

---

Additionally, you could add an invisible 1px border like in the below snippet and it evens out the jagged edges even more. Note that this does add a bit of a blur effect but the edges are less jagged than the above snippet. You could use or ignore this option based on your needs.

```css
#BlockOutside {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  padding: 4px 6px 6px 4px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  transform: skew(10deg) translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#BlockInside {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div id="BlockOutside">
  <div id="BlockInside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's worth noting that this works because it enables hardware acceleration, shifting the rendering from the CPU to the GPU. you can also add `translateZ(0)` to the transform stack to do the same thing, and it might be beneficial to go ahead and include both properties.
this *won't* fix the problem on a device that does not have a dedicated GPU (many mobile devices), since these devices cannot perform hardware acceleration.

Comment: The result is antialiased enough! Thanks!